# CFNetwork crashes app if URLRequest timeout then user authenticates via Kerberos

Tags: ios, alamofire, kerberos, cfnetwork, urlrequest

I develop an enterprise iOS application that uses kerberos for authentication. I have a `timeoutInterval = 30` for each request. 
Authentication and url requests work just fine if user enters the password and passes the password verification before the request timeout. 
If user enters the password after the timeout (30+ seconds after iOS prompts user to), CFNetwork crashes App next time that application calls a web service, as seen below.

I am not sure what causes the issue.

```
Date/Time:       2017-01-24T03:16:42Z
Launch Time:     2017-01-24T03:16:03Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 10.0.2 (14A456)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x68
Crashed Thread:  4

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000189d8816c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018ad85cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
2   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018ad83908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1128
3   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018acb2048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 440
4   GraphicsServices                     0x000000018c735198 GSEventRunModal + 176
5   UIKit                                0x0000000190c85628 -[UIApplication _run] + 680
6   UIKit                                0x0000000190c80360 UIApplicationMain + 204
7   SampleiOSApp                   0x00000001000301bc main (AppDelegate.swift:15)
8   libdyld.dylib                        0x0000000189c945b8 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000189da6a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000189e68db4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000189da6a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000189e68db4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000189d8816c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018ad85cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 188
2   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018ad83908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1128
3   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018acb2048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 440
4   Foundation                           0x000000018b7c0b1c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
5   Foundation                           0x000000018b7e160c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92
6   UIKit                                0x00000001915fac7c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 132
7   Foundation                           0x000000018b8be50c __NSThread__start__ + 1020
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000189e6b860 _pthread_body + 236
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000189e6b770 _pthread_start + 280
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000189e68dbc thread_start + 0

Thread 4 Crashed:
0   CFNetwork                            0x000000018b51ae60 std::__1::__hash_const_iterator<std::__1::__hash_node<std::__1::__hash_value_type<AuthenticationState::AuthInfoType, std::__1::unique_ptr<AuthenticationInfo, std::__1::default_delete<AuthenticationInfo> > >, void*>*> std::__1::__hash_table<std::__1::__hash_value_type<AuthenticationState::AuthInfoType, std::__1::unique_ptr<AuthenticationInfo, std::__1::default_delete<AuthenticationInfo> > >, std::__1::__unordered_map_hasher<AuthenticationState::AuthInfoType, std::__1::__hash_value_type<AuthenticationState::AuthInfoType, std::__1::unique_ptr<AuthenticationInfo, std::__1::default_delete<AuthenticationInfo> > >, AuthenticationState::AuthInfoTypeHasher, true>, std::__1::__unordered_map_equal<AuthenticationState::AuthInfoType, std::__1::__hash_value_type<AuthenticationState::AuthInfoType, std::__1::unique_ptr<AuthenticationInfo, std::__1::default_delete<AuthenticationInfo> > >, std::__1::equal_to<AuthenticationState::AuthInfoType>, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__hash_value_type<AuthenticationState::AuthInfoType, std::__1::unique_ptr<AuthenticationInfo, std::__1::default_delete<AuthenticationInfo> > > > >::find<AuthenticationState::AuthInfoType>(AuthenticationState::AuthInfoType const&) const + 0
1   CFNetwork                            0x000000018b516b90 AuthenticationState::updateState(HTTPResponseMessage*, _CFURLAuthChallenge*, _CFURLCredential const*, __SecTrust*) + 148
2   CFNetwork                            0x000000018b4f8724 HTTPProtocol::_protocolInterface_useCredential(_CFURLCredential const*, _CFURLAuthChallenge*) + 880
3   CFNetwork                            0x000000018b4f7008 ___ZN12HTTPProtocol19askAccountsForCredsEh_block_invoke_2 + 240
4   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000189c611c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
5   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000189c6cb24 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 372
6   CFNetwork                            0x000000018b5f2e98 RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 32
7   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018acb19a8 CFArrayApplyFunction + 64
8   CFNetwork                            0x000000018b5f2d7c RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 132
9   CFNetwork                            0x000000018b5f40a4 MultiplexerSource::perform() + 308
10  CFNetwork                            0x000000018b5f3e10 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 60
11  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018ad86278 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
12  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018ad85bc0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 520
13  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018ad837c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 800
14  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018acb2048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 440
15  CFNetwork                            0x000000018b49fcec +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 332
16  Foundation                           0x000000018b8be50c __NSThread__start__ + 1020
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000189e6b860 _pthread_body + 236
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000189e6b770 _pthread_start + 280
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x0000000189e68dbc thread_start + 0
```

My code for the request is as follows:

```
let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
manager.retrier = RetryingManager()
let request: Alamofire.Request = manager.request(httpRequest as! URLRequestConvertible)
    .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
    .responseObject(queue: queue, completionHandler: {
        (response: DataResponse<T>) in

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                debugPrint("JSON: \(JSON)")
                // callback with the data
                completion(JSON, nil)
            }
        } else if let resultError = response.result.error {
            let errorMessage = WebServerErrorHelper.createErrorMessage(resultError: resultError, statusCode: response.response?.statusCode, serverData: response.data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(nil, errorMessage)
            }
        }
    })
```

Here `queue` is a concurrent `DispatchQueue` and `timeInterval` is set as 30 for `httpRequest`.
I do not have a clue how to solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in `CFNetwork` and it was fixed in iOS 10.3.3